# Is there an Android SDK for Leap Motion?

Tags: c#

I am dealing with Leap Motion but I need the SDK for Android, so it can communicate with it.  Any help or any alternative that will work, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide what you have done so far in this regard (code etc)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)